# Avoid moving back & forward in browser in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

After session expiry am moving current page to login page. If the user clicks on the back or forward button in the browser, it redirects to previous page instead of showing login page. I tried with interceptors to expire the session and to avoid the cache store but still the page moves to previous page instead of login. My code as follows,

**myInterceptor.java**

```
public class myInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

   private static final long serialVersionUID= 1L;
   @Override

   public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {

      final ActionContext context = ai.getInvocationContext();
      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);
      if(response!=null){
         response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
         response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
         response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
      }
      return ai.invoke();
   }
}
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default,json-default">
  <interceptors>
       <interceptor name="myInterceptor"  class="com.webapp.myInterceptor"/>
       <interceptor-stack name="defaultinterStack">
             <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
             <interceptor-ref name="myInterceptor"/>
       </interceptor-stack>
  </interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="defaultinterStack"/>

<action name="home" class="com.webapp.Action" method="home" > 
     <result name="success">/start.jsp</result>
     <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>

</package>
```

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this.

Comment: Browsers often do not reload page, when you go backward/forward, they just show html code they cached previously. I am not sure, if you can do anything about this one.

Comment: @libik yes they don't reload to remove the cache i wrote those three lines to stop caching the html but it fails.

Comment: Well you have to add these headers to all your responses (before losing session), this "intercept" is added only when it is "intercepted", right? But it is too late, because browser does not reload to find out, he should reload :).